# OnEdit & Last Row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-apps

I'm using an onEdit to send a row in data to another tab.  Right now, it fills into the first fully empty row.  Is it possible to have this data filled into a row where certain columns already have info?

For example: the data from onEdit would fill into columns A:K, while there is already information in that same row in column L?

So basically, rather than fill into the first fully empty row, the onEdit would fill the data into the first row where columns A:K are blank, not taking into consideration other columns.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry' + JSON.stringify(e));
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  //master
  if(sh.getName() == "Master1" && e.value=="TRUE") {
    if(e.range.columnStart==13) {
      //e.source.toast('Flag1');
      var tsh=e.source.getSheetByName("Export1");
      var trg=tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1);
    }
    if(e.range.columnStart==14) {
      //e.source.toast('Flag2');
      var tsh=e.source.getSheetByName("Export2");
      var trg=tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1);
    }
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).copyTo(trg);
  }
  //master2
  if(sh.getName()=="Master2" && e.value=="TRUE") {
    if(e.range.columnStart==9) {
      //e.source.toast('Flag1');
      var tsh=e.source.getSheetByName("Export3");
      var trg=tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1); 
    }
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).copyTo(trg)
  }
}
```

Comment: It is indeed possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry' + JSON.stringify(e));
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  //master
  if(sh.getName()=="Master1" && e.value=="TRUE") {
    if(e.range.columnStart==13) {
      //e.source.toast('Flag1');
      var vs=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,11).getValues()
      var tsh=e.source.getSheetByName("Export1");
      tsh.getRange(getColumnHeight(11,tsh,e.source)+1,1,1,11).setValues(vs);
    }
    if(e.range.columnStart==14) {
      //e.source.toast('Flag2');
      var vs=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,11).getValues()
      var tsh=e.source.getSheetByName("Export2");
      tsh.getRange(getColumnHeight(11,tsh,e.source)+1,1,1,11).setValues(vs);
    }

  }
  //master2
  if(sh.getName()=="Master2" && e.value=="TRUE") {
    if(e.range.columnStart==9) {
      //e.source.toast('Flag1');
      var vs=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,8).getValues()
      var tsh=e.source.getSheetByName("Export3");
      tsh.getRange(getColumnHeight(8,tsh,e.source)+1,1,1,8).setValues(vs);
    }
  }
}

function getColumnHeight(col,sh,ss){
  var ss=ss||SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=sh||ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col=col||sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var v=sh.getRange(1,col,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues().map(function(r){return r[0];});
  var s=0;
  var h=0;
  v.forEach(function(e,i){if(e==''){s++;}else{s=0;}h++;});
  return (h-s);
}
```

Comment: That's so great! Thanks @Cooper I really appreciate it!

Comment: I'm glad you added that comment because I realized I didn't include the getColumnHeight Code.

Comment: Hey @Cooper - I am such an idiot, I have been trying to pair your concept with the full code I have now in my question (edited).  I thought I'd be able to alter the lines of code to match what you added, but somehow I am still struggling. Is that possible? No worries if it is a big issue for you, although it seems like you can solve anything! lol!